# Sculpting - only vertical Strokes seem to work

Tags: modeling, sculpting

I am trying to model an elephant with horizontal strokes. However whenever I try, it doesn't work at all. Only vertical strokes seem to work.

video of the problem is here: https://www.reddit.com/r/blender/comments/gfzo3q/modelling_is_only_allowing_vertical_strokes/

Answer (score 0):

Enable Dynamic Topology Horizontal probably isn't working because you do not have enough vertices to work around.

Comment: OMG THXXXXX! I was legit dying

Comment: Hi @moosekhan786 - instead of posting "thanks", consider [upvoting and accepting the answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers), if it solved your problem. StackExchange is not a forum, it's a Q&A site.